# Observable Data Services with one-to-many relationship

Tags: angular, observable

I try to implement the Angular Observable Data Services in my code but I am kind of confused by the approach.

I have the following data model : Theme --- one-to-many ---> Category

**Theme**

```
export class Theme {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  iconCode: string;
  categories: Category[];
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
```

**Category**

```
export class Category {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
```

I wrote this code for the Observable Data Service of the Theme :

```
export class ThemeStoreService {

  private _themes: BehaviorSubject<Theme[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Theme[]>([]);
  private dataStore: {
    themes: Theme[]
  };

  constructor(private themeBackendService: ThemeBackendService) {
    this.dataStore = { themes: [] };
    this._themes = new BehaviorSubject<Theme[]>([]);
  }

  get themes() {
    return this._themes.asObservable();
  }
```

And I am wondering about the writing of the Observable Data Service of the Category which is linked to the Theme.
In my project, I am using a navbar which is a list a theme containing a sublist of categories. I'd like to refresh the list and the sublist after the creation of a new category.

- Do I need to also use a BehaviorSubject for the Category?
- How can I do the link between these two object?

Below, my actual code for the Observable Data Service of the Category :

```
export class CategoryStoreService {

  private _categories: Observable<Category[]>
  private dataStore: {
    categories: Category[]
  };

  constructor(private themeStoreService: ThemeStoreService) {
    this.dataStore = { categories: [] };
    this._categories = this.themeStoreService.themes.pipe(
      map(themes => {
        themes.forEach(theme => {
          theme.categories = this.dataStore.categories;
        })
      })
    )
  }

  get categories() {
    return this._categories;
  }
```

Any feedback or example to help me?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning _themes as observable which is a new instance of type `BehaviorSubject<Theme[]>`, and when you are receiving that in theme, it becomes of type `BehaviourSubject<Theme[]>`, then you do some assignment to its category part but as a whole theme remains of type `BehaviourSubject<Theme[]>`. But when you are assigning it to this._categories which is of type `Observable<Category[]>`, that is a mismatch.
For Solution, you can return _themes.categories or receive themes instead of _categories.

I hope this must be creating the mismatch of type.